# python. get data from text file and put into dataframe

Tags: python

I have a txt file of both text and data. I want to get the state name, year, All Donor Types, Deceased Donor, Living Donor. 
The file contains state level donation panel data. I want to get rid of the first time series of all donor state data, get rid of the explanation text, when finding a state name, get rid of the To date aggregate level of donation data of the state after the state name, collect the yearly donation data starting with year, put the state name ahead of the yearly data. Unitll there is a new state name, the yearly data after the explanation text belong to the last state.

```
            All Donor Types Deceased Donor  Living Donor
 All Donor States of Residence   To Date        360,673 205,858 154,815
     2018       7,107   4,394   2,713
     2017       16,478  10,286  6,192
     2016       15,944  9,971   5,973
     2015       15,071  9,079   5,992
     2014       14,415  8,596   5,819
Data subject to change based on future data submission or correction.
Donor : Donor Type by Donor State of Residence, Donation Year   Page 2 of 70
Donors Recovered : January 1, 1988 - May 31, 2018
For Format = Landscape
Based on OPTN data as of July 4, 2018

            All Donor Types Deceased Donor  Living Donor
     1993       7,766   4,861   2,905
     1992       7,091   4,520   2,571
 Alabama     To Date        5,926   3,471   2,455
     2018       95  65  30
     2017       259 172 87
     2016       249 175 74
 Alaska  To Date        935 565 370
     2018       14  9   5
     2017       42  32  10
     2016       30  22  8
Data subject to change based on future data submission or correction.
Donor : Donor Type by Donor State of Residence, Donation Year   Page 70 of 70
Donors Recovered : January 1, 1988 - May 31, 2018
For Format = Landscape
Based on OPTN data as of July 4, 2018

            All Donor Types Deceased Donor  Living Donor
     1989       16  12  4
     1988       16  11  5
```

I want to get the yearly data after the state name Alabama and Alaska, get rid of the text, the first group of all states donation data, and the "To Date" aggregate value after each state name.
At last, I want

```
state year all deceased living
Alabama 2018 95 65 30
Alabama 2017 259 172 87
Alabama 2016 249 175 74
Alaska 2018 14  9 5
Alaska 2017 42 32 10
Alaska 2016 30  22  8
Alaska 1989  16 12  4
Alaska 1988  16 11  5
```

I tried a lot, the code

```
import pandas as pd
fname = "optn.txt"
fh = open(fname)
count = 0
state=['Alabama','Alaska','Arizona','Arkansas',
'California','Colorado','Connecticut','Delaware',
'District of Columbia','Florida']
year=['2018','2017','2016','2015','2014','2013','2012',
'2011','2010','2009','2008','2007','2006','2005','2004',
'2003','2002','2001','2000','1999','1998','1997','1996',
'1995','1994','1993','1992','1991','1990','1989','1988']
optny=list()
for line in fh:
    line = line.strip()
    #print(line)
    if not line.startswith(tuple(year)):continue
    optny.append(line)
    #break
print(optny)
```

Till now I could get all the lines starting with state name or year and put them into a list called optny. And I could print the list out. The list contains the all state data, and the To date aggregate data which should be got rid of. I want to put it into dataframe and then get rid of the unuuseful data and put state name to each row. Couldn't achieve it still.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a task where regular expressions are useful.

Note that for my current solution, the format needs to be the same as in your example.

First, identify unnecessary strings

```
import re

clean_pattern = re.compile(
    r"(^[A-Z].+)|All Donor Types Deceased Donor  Living Donor", 
    re.MULTILINE
)
```

This pattern matches the lines which start with a capital letter like "Data subject ..." but ignores lines which, e.g., start with white space followed by other characters. The second part also matches the "All Donor Types..." lines.

Next, find states and the table content with the following pattern

```
state_pattern = re.compile(
    r"^\s+(?P<state>[a-zA-Z]+)\s+To Date[0-9, ]+\n(?P<content>[0-9, \n]+)$", 
    re.MULTILINE
)
```

Right now, I assume that states are just made out of one word, they are the first word in the sentence and they are followed by "To Date". Also, since the text was cleaned beforehand, it should just contain data out of numbers and commas. The next words will form a different state / content entry.

And last but not least, define the data pattern

```
data_pattern = re.compile(
    r"(?P<year>[0-9]{4})\s+(?P<all>[0-9,]+)\s+(?P<deceased>[0-9,]+)\s+(?P<living>[0-9,]+)"
)
```

Having defined the patterns, one can now extract the data (assuming the full text is stored in `text`)

```
data = []
# remove the unwanted lines
cleaned_text = clean_pattern.sub('', text)
# iterate over state / content matches
for state_match in state_pattern.finditer(cleaned_text):
    info_dict = state_match.groupdict()
    # iterate over data matches
    for match in data_pattern.finditer(info_dict['content']):
        data_dict = match.groupdict()
        # add the state information to the data
        data_dict['state'] = info_dict['state']
        data.append(data_dict)

pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['state', 'year', 'all', 'deceased', 'living'])
```